# “Internal error: An unexpected exception occurred.” when filtering simple dimension that has ragged parent-child hierarchy in multidimensional model

Tags: ssas

Platform: SQL Server Analysis Services 2016 RTM and later (Multidimensional)

In the **database** we have the following **dimension of companies**:
[Company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A11X.png)

The parent-child hierarchy does not loop but it’s ragged. The **graph** looks as follows (treant-js drawing):
[Company parent-child graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUM1t.png)

The Analysis Services project contains **only one dimension** - Company, **created using the wizard**. All **settings are set with default values**. “CompanySK” is the KeyColumn and “CompanyName” is the NameColumn. “CompanyParentSK” was renamed to “Company Hierarchy” and Usage was set to “Parent”, which indicates this attribute holds parent id. Nothing unusual:
[Dimension in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ng8t.png)

The project is **always loaded and processed without problems**.
The hierarchy works and is represented correctly in the tree viewer.

Now if we will try to **query the dimension using MDX** just like Reporting Services is doing - strange things are happening..

When you try to **list all Companies where “Country Name” is “Germany”**:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Company].[Company Name].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Company].[Company Name].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Company].[Company Name].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
SELECT {
[Measures].[ParameterCaption],
[Measures].[ParameterValue],
[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
} ON COLUMNS , 
[Company].[Company Name].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [HierarchyErrorCube]
WHERE STRTOSET( "{[Company].[Country Name].&[Germany]}" );
```

**it returns an error:**

```
Executing the query ...
Internal error: An unexpected exception occurred.
Run complete
```

BUT if you will ask for Australia:

```
(...)
WHERE STRTOSET( "{[Company].[Country Name].&[Australia]}" );
```

it just works.

Few interesting facts:

- If you will remove/comment [Measures].[ParameterCaption] from the selection - query starts to work,
- if you will disable “Company Hierarchy” by changing it back to regular attribute - query starts to work,
- removing the filter (WHERE) makes the query working,
- so as you can see - even if “Company Hierarchy” is not a part of any query listed above, it affects somehow the engine and fails the query when it comes to retrieving CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION on “Company Name” attribute when another attribute - “Country Name” - is filtered. And not for all filtered values, but we couldn’t find any pattern here (for example if country level affects somehow).
- Using SQL Server Profiler (with enabled all events in capture scope) and sniffing one of the failing queries, it is clear, that the error is appearing during last phase of getting members - exactly for CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION.

You can download the project and data [here on my blogpost.](http://sql.pawlikowski.pro/2019/07/18/internal-error-an-unexpected-exception-occurred-when-trying-to-filter-simple-dimension-that-has-ragged-parent-child-hierarchy-in-multidimensional-model/). You can also find there all the ways that we've tried to resolve this issue.

**Is it there any setting in Visual Studio project that can help or maybe the Reporting Services MDX code is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.**